# Large memory usage in cassandra connection

Tags: memory, cassandra, prepared-statement

I am doing many async inserts into cassandra using the [C# Datastax connector](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver) and  a single cluster and session object. I am also using prepared statements and reuse them for all operations.

Recently I noticed that after a few minutes of running the application becomes very slow because it was starting to use virtual memory on a machine with 32 GB of memory.
I traced the memory usage and found that it is all being used by the cassandra connection.

For testing I ran until the memory was 1 GB and noticed the following:

943 MB in Cassandra.Connection
890 MB in Cassandra.OperationState
802 MB in RequestExecution
738 MB in RequestHandler

I also noticed that there was about 934 MB in ConcurrentQueue which is rooted in Cassandra.Connection._writeQueue.

Does this mean the application is queuing writes faster than the node can handle?
All logic is performed using async await with prepared statements.

Not sure how I could do things differently. This is fairly basic cassandra usage.

This was posted at the [official google group](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/csharp-driver-user/v61MaGlG8Rg). However it appears that SO may be a better location. I am frankly not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, it sounds like you're throwing writes at the cluster faster than it can acknowledge them and, thus the write queue is backing up. It sounds like you're already following best practices like using a single session object, prepared statements, etc. but there are a few things you could try and see if it helps the problem:

1. When you're creating the `Session` object take a look at customizing the `PoolingOptions` (i.e. use `.WithPoolingOptions(yourCustomPoolingOptions)` on the cluster builder. It's possible that increasing the number of connections per node or the max number of in-flight requests may help. But keep in mind, you'll still use more memory for all the bookkeeping (i.e. Tasks, etc.) that has to happen for async requests. Read more about the [connection pooling in the driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.2/features/connection-pooling/).
2. Throttle the writes in your application if you have control over the source. For example, if you're reading from a flat file and then writing rows to Cassandra, keep track of how many writes you have in flight and only pull more data from the file when you're below some threshold that gives you a steady state in the application. This is a really common pattern I've seen for bulk loading data or loading big batches of data into Cassandra.
3. Check things on the Cassandra side also. It may be that you have something going on there that's slowing down the writes and thus backing up your client (stop the world garbage collections, compaction, etc.). A good place to start is warnings/errors in the logs (e.g. the `system.log`). You can also get a ton of metrics from [`nodetool`](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/nodetool.html) (where the `tablestats` and `tablehistograms` commands might be useful).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It certainly would be nice if everything magically worked the way you think it should, but this is the real world after all. :(